# Horizontal scrolling in TextView by program

Tags: java, android, layout, scroll

I've got a single lined TextView with a text in it that is too long to be displayed at once. Now I want the app to scroll horizontally smoothly to a certain position in the text when the user does certain things. So the scrolling is initiated by user actions but the user doesn't decide himself to which position the app will scroll (so I don't want to implement usual scrolling by swiping). I'd like to have a function `scrollTo(int position)` which accomplishes the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use an EditText and animate the selection property. You can easily style it to behave like a TextView if that's important, for instance:

```
<EditText
    android:enabled="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/ttt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="very long text" 
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

And then use property animation to scroll smoothly:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourEditText, "selection", from, to);
anim.setDuration(duration);
anim.start();
```

Note that you should not use a hard coded color for the text because on some phones the background might be different (too dark, for instance). If you have your own theme or using Holo light it you're good, but you should be aware of a possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=" This post will help to share your urls and text values into social networks like facebook,twitter and linkedin.in facebook we have to share your urls only, but twitter and linkedin able to share both urls and text." />
</LinearLayout>
```